# SFDX: force:source:pull fails due to deleted fields

Tags: salesforcedx

Pulling changes from a scratch org, `sfdx force:source:status` shows many changes, including:

```
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Contact_del__c            CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.User__c                   CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Company__c                CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Role__c                   CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Relation_del__c           CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Title__c                  CustomField
Remote Add      XX_Lead__c.Relationship_Owner__c     CustomField
```

Note the two deleted fields (`XX_Lead__c.Contact_del__c` and `XX_Lead__c.Relationship_Owner__c`).  So when I try to pull the changes, I get this:

> ERROR:  Entity of type 'CustomField' named 'XX_Lead__c.Contact_del__c' cannot be found
>
> Entity of type 'CustomField' named 'XX_Lead__c.Relation_del__c' cannot be found.

Is this a known issue?  I was able to work around the issue by permanently deleting ('erase'-ing) the deleted fields (via Classic setup).

Comment: same issue with me, i've created some custom metadata, deleted them without have done a pull, now i can't pull any changes because the custom metadata was deleted...